# pam_access.so is not working when listsep is specified

Tags: 18.04, pam

I ran into a strange issue with configuring PAM trying to restrict ssh logins by pam_access.so with package `libpam-modules_1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.1.`

contents of */etc/security/access.conf*

```
+ : root : ALL
+ : devops : ALL
#+ : computer managers : ALL
- : ALL : ALL
```

contents of */etc/pam.d/sshd*

`account required pam_access.so listsep=, debug`

with this setting, each and every user is allowed to login no matter whether they're in any specified group or not.
If i remove `listsep=,` from PAM config, then it works as it supposed to.

from debug logs It looks like whenever `listsep` is specified it is not returning any error when it can't find the user group in access.conf AKA pam_access.so will always return success with listsep.

In below context user is a member of "computer managers" but not "devops"

Debug logs with listsep enabled and only devops in access.conf

```
pam_access(sshd:account): line 1: +  :  root  :  ALL
pam_access(sshd:account): list_match: list= root , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match: tok= root , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): string_match: tok= root , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match=0, "user"
pam_access(sshd:account): line 2: +  :  devops  :  ALL
pam_access(sshd:account): list_match: list= devops , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match: tok= devops , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): string_match: tok= devops , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match=0, "user"
pam_access(sshd:account): line 4: -  :  ALL  :  ALL
pam_access(sshd:account): list_match: list= ALL , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match: tok= ALL , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): string_match: tok= ALL , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match=0, "user"
Accepted password for user from IP port PORT ssh2
```

see the last pam_access log line `user_match=0`. let's compare it with logs from when listsep is not specified

```
pam_access(sshd:account): line 1: +  :  root  :  ALL
pam_access(sshd:account): list_match: list= root , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match: tok=root, item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): string_match: tok=root, item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match=0, "user"
pam_access(sshd:account): line 2: +  :  devops  :  ALL
pam_access(sshd:account): list_match: list= devops , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match: tok=devops, item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): string_match: tok=devops, item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match=0, "user"
pam_access(sshd:account): line 4: -  :  ALL  :  ALL
pam_access(sshd:account): list_match: list= ALL , item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match: tok=ALL, item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): string_match: tok=ALL, item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): user_match=2, "user"
pam_access(sshd:account): list_match: list= ALL, item=user
pam_access(sshd:account): from_match: tok=ALL, item=IP
pam_access(sshd:account): string_match: tok=ALL, item=IP
pam_access(sshd:account): from_match=2, "IP"
pam_access(sshd:account): access denied for user 'user' from 'IP'
```

I can confirm when `listsep=,` specified it's correctly parsing the group "computer managers", but failing to return error codes.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Are there any work arounds when the groupname contains spaces?

Thanks in advance,

Bhanu

Comment: I wonder if that's a genuine bug, whereby setting the `listsep` to something other than whitespace causes the `ALL` to be tokenized as `ALL ` (with a trailing space) - so that `user` fails to match the `- : ALL : ALL` rule?

Comment: Looks like, that's the issue. I have to get rid of all the extra spaces other than the ones in group names.

Answer (score 0):

In your debug log, you can see, that `list` is using whitespace.

```
...
pam_access(sshd:account): list_match: list= root , item=user
...
pam_access(sshd:account): list_match: list= devops , item=user
...
pam_access(sshd:account): list_match: list= ALL , item=user
...
```

Note that whitespaces around  `root`  and  `devops`  and  `ALL` .

> with this setting, each and every user is allowed to login no matter whether they're in any specified group or not.

This is a correct behaviour, since you've defined in the `/etc/security/access.conf` rules with whitespaces (`+ : root : ALL`), whereas you've set, that the `listsep=,` is comma and not space. So no user is part of the  `ALL` , since the special keyword is `ALL` (without whitespaces).

The correct solution would be the `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
account required pam_access.so listsep=, debug
```

And the `/etc/security/access.conf`:

```
+:root:ALL
+:devops:ALL
+:computer managers:ALL
-:ALL:ALL
```

And I gues, that `devops` and `computer managers` are groups, therefore we you should use paranthesis to denote group:

```
+:root:ALL
+:(devops):ALL
+:(computer managers):ALL
-:ALL:ALL
```

Sources:

```
$ man pam_access
...
       listsep=separators
           This option modifies the list separator character that pam_access will recognize when parsing the access configuration file. For example:
           listsep=, will cause the default ` ' (space) and `\t' (tab) characters to be treated as part of a list element value and `,' becomes the
           only list element separator. Doing this may be useful on a system with group information obtained from a Windows domain, where the default
           built-in groups "Domain Users", "Domain Admins" contain a space.
...
$ man access.conf
...
       The second field, the users/group field, should be a list of one or more login names, group names, or ALL (which always matches). To
       differentiate user entries from group entries, group entries should be written with brackets, e.g.  (group).
...
```